# How can I center this UL inside the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm currently creating a theme from a PSD.

You can see the navbar in question here

http://www.webdesigndarwen.co.uk/cassanni2

I want the UL with "Home , Who We are, Our stands" etc to be centered horizontally inside it's parent div.

Anybody help?

Comment: Just using that doesn't have any effect on it unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if

```
.navbar .nav {
float: none;
}
```

gives the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the margin as txpeaseofficer09 suggested, you need to remove your float, and give the element a non percentage size.

Try this in cassanni.css (The selector needs to be a level more granular than bootstraps .navbar .nav):

```
.navbar ul.nav {
width: 900px;
float: none;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Levi I did this and it seems to work, I changed the width to 960px however

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

The first number is the top margin so you can adjust that if you need.  auto will attempt to automatically define values for right, bottom and left which if you are using the HTML5 `<nav>` element then the `<ul>` inside the `<nav>` should automatically center itself.

Comment: If you do `display: inline;` then you don't have to set static size on the `<ul>` or the `<nav>`, but you should not use float.

Comment: Thanks txpeaceoffer, along with Levi's suggestion I got it to work!

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do the pixel width unless you know precisely the size you want everything, but if you have found an answer you like, please, accept that answer.